# Docker-compose container exit with code 0

Tags: docker-compose, dock

I am learning docker. whenever  i am doing docker-compose up then my `memcached` service is exited with code 0. I have googled this issue and found that it is happening because `service memcached start` command is running in the brackground and after this command there is no process running in the foreground and hence container exit immediately if there is no process running in the foreground.

Below is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3"
services:
 app:
   build: .
   volumes: 
    - .:/project 
   command: 'rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000' 
   container_name: 'test_rails'
   ports:
    - 3000:3000
   depends_on:
     - database
 database:
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes:
    - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: docker-user
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: docker-password
    POSTGRES_DB: docker-db
 memcached:
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: Dockerfile.memcached
  command: bash -c "service memcached start"
  expose: 
   - "11211"
  tty: true
```

Below is my Dockerfile.memcached file

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04 
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y  memcached
RUN apt-get install -y libmemcached-tools
```

To resovle this issue, there are various hack availble such as use `tail -f /dev/null` command so that it will run forever in the foreground and container will never exit but it seems hack to me and not concrete solution. can someone help me in finding concrete solution and not hack for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an official image of memcached https://hub.docker.com/_/memcached

The service will be like:

```
memcached:
    image: memcached:latest
    ports:
      - "11212:11211"
```